# ¿Cómo solucionar el problema al momento de generar un QR con PHP?

Tags: php, qrcode, generador

Estoy tratando de generar un código QR, aparentemente, no hay error alguno hablando sintácticamente, pero muestra ese error(se adjunta más abajo). Estoy usando **phpqrcode** para tratar de generarla. Adjunto el código de igual manera.

**ERROR MOSTRADO**:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\multi-test\crearQR\Intendo2\libs\phpqrcode\qrimage.php:74 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\multi-test\crearQR\Intendo2\libs\phpqrcode\qrimage.php(32): QRimage::image(Array, 10, 3) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\multi-test\crearQR\Intendo2\libs\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(494): QRimage::png(Array, 'qrs/test.png', 10, 3, false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\multi-test\crearQR\Intendo2\libs\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(286): QRencode->encodePNG('Alejandro Ihuit...', 'qrs/test.png', false) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\multi-test\crearQR\Intendo2\index.php(14): QRcode::png('Alejandro Ihuit...', 'qrs/test.png', 'M', 10, 3) #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\multi-test\crearQR\Intendo2\libs\phpqrcode\qrimage.php on line 74

---

**CÓDIGO**:

```
<?php
    require'libs/phpqrcode/qrlib.php';
    $qr_dir = 'qrs/';
    if(!file_exists($qr_dir))
    {
        mkdir($qr_dir);
        console.log("Carpeta creada");
    }
    $qr_name = $qr_dir.'test.png';
    $qr_size = 10;
    $qr_level = 'M';
    $qr_frameSize = 3;
    $contenido = 'Samuel H.';
    QRcode::png($contenido, $qr_name, $qr_level, $qr_size, $qr_frameSize);

    echo '<img src="'.$qr_name.'" />';
?>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para cambiar las imágenes por texto (error y código), para poder analizarlo más fácilmente y tratar de ayudarte a encontrar el error.

Comment: Listo, espero sea más entendible ahora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente, no había que instalar la librería GD, basta con localizar el archivo php.ini, y quitarle el ";" que está antes de la palabra extension.

con esto solo anduvo perfecto

puntualmente en
Notes for Windows environments

```
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
extension=gettext
```

se le saca el ; , y listo, por las dudas, stop a apachey start nuevamente

Answer (score 1):

Te falta instalar gd en tu PHP para pode tener esas funcionalidades

http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

En tu instalación windows, posiblemente sea disponer correctamente la librería php_gd2.dll

Comment: Me ayudó mucho tu comentario, me orientó; ya pude solucionar el error. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente, no había que instalar la librería GD, basta con localizar el archivo **php.ini**, y quitarle el **";"** que está antes de la palabra **extension**.